# How to retrive data from Accu-check with React Native

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, mobile-application, data-transfer

I am trying to make a React Native application to read the data from  Accu-Chek Guide meter but I don't have enough knowledge about BLE communications, please provide some info about this

I haven't started the coding part as I don't have much info about this.

Comment: Hello, always start with a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile), especially if you do not have any documentation about the BLE interface of your device. But having access to a documentation would be best, not all BLE device follow a standard, it is perfectly valid to use something else which would make it hard to reverse engineer